# Preg_replace not replacing correctly

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

Im working on a project of mine, where people can add pieces of php code into my database.
To display these im using SyntaxHighlighter. Im using preg_replace to escape all the < brackets within pre tags. This is needed so syntaxhighlighter renders the code properly. It works fine on php tags and stuff..

This is my code to render the input from my database:

```
 public function renderPre($input) // Function to escape html brackets within PRE tags. 
{
    $temp = preg_replace('/<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>/ise', "'<pre>' . htmlspecialchars('$1') . '</pre>'", $input);  
    return str_replace('<pre>', '<pre class=\'brush: php\'>', $temp);
}
```

Once the brackets have been escaped i add a class to the pre tag to activate the highlighter.

In my database the code is stored like this :

```
<pre><?php
foreach ($tutorial as $row)
{
    echo "<h1>".$row['title']."</h1>";
    echo $this->content_model->renderPre($row['intro']);
    echo $this->content_model->renderPre($row['body']);
}
?></pre>
```

Now on my actual page, where the code is retrieved from the database and displayed in the highlighter, this is the output :

```
<?php
foreach ($tutorial as $row)
{
    echo \"<h1>\".$row['title'].\"</h1>\";
    echo $this->content_model->renderPre($row['intro']);
    echo $this->content_model->renderPre($row['body']);
}
?>
```

At the line where the H1 tag is, it adds a few extra slashes ( \ )
I dont know why it does this. It must have something to do with the /ise in the render function.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!!

edit :

The code to retrieve stuff from the database :

```
    public function get_tutorial()
    {
        $sql = "Select
  tutorial.*,
  category.name,
  category.slug As slug1
From
  tutorial Inner Join
  category On tutorial.category_id = category.id
  WHERE tutorial.slug = '".$this->uri->segment(3)."'
  ";

  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code used to write data to and read data from the database?

Comment: added the code to read the data, havent made the code to insert it yet, added it manually to the database

Comment: It works fine for me (see [codepad](http://codepad.org/doIwcpnw)). On another note, why do you have this `$temp`? Why not just replace with `"'<pre class=\"brush: php\">' . htmlspecialchars('$1') . '</pre>'"` from the start and return that? (eg: http://codepad.org/9IDycZuY)

Comment: that is because the <pre> has no class in the database, i will try it out the way you suggest it

Comment: @DavidEricsson Yes, but only the replacement has a class, not the regexp

Comment: I used your code, the output still adds those extra slashes near the h1 tags :(

Comment: Are [magic quotes](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) enabled? Or broader question, are you escaping that data when you enter it into the database (either manually with `real_escape_string()` or automatically as with magic quotes)?

Comment: Im not escaping data, ive entered it manually in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers. I got it working correctly by adding stripslashes to the renderpre function :

```
 public function renderPre($input) // Function to escape html brackets within PRE tags. 
{
    $temp = preg_replace('/<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>/ise', "'<pre>' . htmlspecialchars('$1') . '</pre>'", $input);  
    return str_replace('<pre>', '<pre class=\'brush: php\'>', stripslashes($temp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function renderPre($input) // Function to escape html brackets within PRE tags. 
{
    $input = htmlspecialchars_decode($input);
    $temp = preg_replace('/<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>/ise', "'<pre>' . htmlspecialchars('$1') . '</pre>'", $input);  
    return str_replace('<pre>', '<pre class=\'brush: php\'>', $temp);
}
```

Comment: i asume u mean htmlspecialchars , since unhtml special chars is not working. When i use your code it doesn't render properly at all :p Thanks for the answer tho!